# Understanding sampler

Tags: ios, instruments

I have a location based app that runs in the background indefinetly.
The battery drains quite fast so I used Sampler to see what was going on while app was in the background. It's supposed not to do anything while in background unless a location change happens.

this is what Sampler returns:
[image]

I see XMPPModule deactivate, is taking 24.1% while it shouldn't be running at all. I set breakpoints on this block and they are never called, so what does this mean exactly then?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The XMPPModule may be a "red herring".  I'd advise using Instruments "Energy Diagnostics" over Sampler to trace battery drain issues.

Comment: I did, while in background the Energy Usage, in a test of 47 mins 34 mins it was consuming 1/20 and the rest 0/20. Not sure if that's a lot or not.